# Selecting rows in which more than one value are in another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with the following form:

```
      day         u           a
 0 2018-03-01   5658599  suggestion
 1 2018-03-01  10405594  suggestion
 2 2018-03-01   4142545  suggestion
 3 2018-03-01  10397546  suggestion
 4 2018-03-01  10296737  suggestion
```

And I want to select the pairs of `(day, u)` that appear in:

```
     user_id access_date access_platform
 0  10405592  2018-03-01             IOS
 1  10405594  2018-03-01         ANDROID
 2  10405593  2018-03-01         ANDROID
 3  10405596  2018-03-01         ANDROID
 4  10405597  2018-03-01         ANDROID
```

Where `u` and `user_id` are the same as well as `day` and `access_date` for the same row.

The DataFrames are huge, is there a efficient way of doing it that doesn't require to iterate row by row one of the dataframes?

A entry of `(day, u)` can appear multiple times in a DataFrame, there are other fields which are not showing.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'user_id': 'u', 'access_date': 'day'}))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is an inner merge:

```
res = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_on=['day', 'u'],
                right_on=['access_date', 'user_id'])\
         .loc[:, df1.columns]

print(res)

          day         u           a
0  2018-03-01  10405594  suggestion
```

Comment: Thank you it worked, I tried before doing something similar but it didn't work, this worked!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for remove possible duplicates in both `DataFrame`s:

```
df1 = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['day','u'])
df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset=['access_date','user_id'])
```

---

```
df = df2.merge(df1, left_on=['access_date','user_id'], right_on=['day','u'])[['day','u']]

print (df)
          day         u
0  2018-03-01  10405594
```

```
@piRSquareds comment solution
df = (df1.merge(df2.rename(columns={'user_id': 'u', 'access_date': 'day'}))[['day','u']])

print (df)
          day         u
0  2018-03-01  10405594
```

If want all columns:

```
df = df2.merge(df1, left_on=['access_date','user_id'], right_on=['day','u'])[df1.columns]
print (df)

          day         u           a
0  2018-03-01  10405594  suggestion
```